# Django CSRF token without a browser

Tags: django, websocket, socket.io, csrf

I have a web app (a game) that I've implemented using django.  The regular django views work just fine with CSRF tokens, but I also want to have computer players talk to the server.  I'm using websockets (django-socketio), and so the computer players need to connect to the SocketIOServer, but the first request in the socket.io protocol is a post, and django responds with a CSRF verification failure.  How can I get a CSRF cookie set without a browser?  (Or just bypass the CSRF verification for the computer players, but that seems a bit unsecure.)

The code that I'm trying to use to connect the computer players to the server looks like this:

```
def connect(self, host, port):
    conn  = httplib.HTTPConnection(host + ':' + str(port))
    conn.request('POST','/socket.io/1/')
    resp  = conn.getresponse()
    resp_text = resp.read()
    print resp_text
    hskey = resp_text.split(':')[0]
    websocket.enableTrace(True)
    url = 'ws://' + host + ':' + str(port) + '/socket.io/1/'
    ws = websocket.WebSocketApp(url + 'websocket/' + hskey,
            on_message=self.on_message,
            on_close=self.on_close)
    ws.on_open = self.on_open
    try:
        ws.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ws.close()
```

Somewhere before I place the post request I need to get a CSRF token.  Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

CSRF protection can be disabled via `csrf_exempt` decorator, please check this example:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt, csrf_protect

@csrf_exempt
def my_view(request):
    # you code here
```

you can check more about it in the official django documentation:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-protection-should-be-disabled-for-just-a-few-views